# Problem with Create Equally Distanced Points on Transect

Tags: r, distance

I try to use CurveTransect to Create Equally Distanced Points on Transect.
https://github.com/esbach/CurveTransect

However, I always meet an error.

```r
transectXY = data.frame(matrix(nrow=11, ncol=2))
colnames(transectXY) = c("x", "y")
transectXY$x = c(1096002, 1096052, 1096002, 1095952, 1096002, 1096052, 1096002, 1095952, 1096002, 1096052, 1096002)
transectXY$y = c(-39178.7, -39078.7, -38978.7, -38878.7, -38778.7, -38678.7, -38578.7, -38478.7, -38378.7, -38278.7, -38178.7)
transectXY = data.matrix(transectXY)
library(Orcs) #coords2Line
transect = coords2Lines(transectXY, ID="A") # transectXY into line
library(smoothr) #curve smoothing
transect = smooth(transect, method="chaikin") # smooth line
projected = CRS("+proj=utm +zone=17 +ellps=intl +units=m +datum=WGS84 +no_defs") # add a crs
proj4string(transect) = projected

plot(transect)
print(plot)

library(rgeos) # gLength
length = round(gLength(transect))

transectXY = data.matrix(transect@lines[[1]]@Lines[[1]]@coords)
**transectXY = observerXY(transect=transectXY, spacing=1)**   in this step!!
```

> Error in is.data.frame(frame) :
> trying to get slot "lines" from an object of a basic class ("matrix") with no slots

I can't fix this problem. Can someone help me? Thanks!

This error message is indicating that the function is trying to access a slot called "lines" from an object of class "matrix", which does not have any slots.

I try to convert the matrix to a data frame using the `as.data.frame()` function before passing it to the `observerXY()` function.

However, it can not work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the example did not match the correct version of the function "observerXY." The function takes a SpatialLinesDataFrame and does the second to last line you posted automatically (i.e., you don't need `transectXY = data.matrix(transect@lines[[1]]@Lines[[1]]@coords)`.

After `length = round(gLength(transect))`, you can use the following:

```
transectXY = observerXY(transect=transect, spacing=1)
```

Here is a fully reproducible result:

```
library(Orcs)
library(smoothr)
library(sp)
library(CurveTransect)

transectXY = data.frame(matrix(nrow=11, ncol=2))
colnames(transectXY) = c("x", "y")
transectXY$x = c(1096002, 1096052, 1096002, 1095952, 1096002, 1096052, 1096002, 1095952, 1096002, 1096052, 1096002)
transectXY$y = c(-39178.7, -39078.7, -38978.7, -38878.7, -38778.7, -38678.7, -38578.7, -38478.7, -38378.7, -38278.7, -38178.7)
transectXY = data.matrix(transectXY)
transect = coords2Lines(transectXY, ID="A") # transectXY into line
transect = smooth(transect, method="chaikin") # smooth line
projected = CRS("+proj=utm +zone=17 +ellps=intl +units=m +datum=WGS84 +no_defs") # add a crs
proj4string(transect) = projected

transectXY = observerXY(transect=transect, spacing=100)

coordinates(transectXY) = ~x.obs + y.obs

plot(transect)
points(transectXY, col="red", pch=20)
```